# idle_in_transaction_session_timeout fall down my application

Tags: postgresql

I have application powered by moodle API 3.3 when I active this parameter at postgresql.conf "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" and restart the service, I get my application down because of losing connection to the database, I tried to put it 300000 milliseconds but no hope once I restart the postgresql I get my application down so any advises ?

Comment: Check postgreSQL log file: do you have a lot of FATAL error messages `FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout` ? Is it the same error on the application side ? 300000 ms = 5 minutes. Do you have this error only after 5 minutes or much sooner ?

Comment: I have this error directly once I restart the postgresql service my web application gonna die

Comment: Looks like your application is using a single connection to the database and that this single connection opens a pending transaction (i.e. a transaction that stays too long open - without COMMIT and ROLLBACK - with respect to "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" value). To investigate this you can try to configure Postgres to log all connections with `log_connections=all` and possibly the statements with  `log_statement=all` for a limited period of time or maybe easier trace your SQL code from the application.

Answer (score 2):

You have to fix your application code so that it closes all transactions immediately after they are done. Then the problem will disappear.